# Why when radio button is checked the images are not sliding out of out of container?

Tags: html, css

As I said Why when radio button is checked the images are not sliding out of out of container? because I want to create image slider with pure css. I have used also with position:absolute; with left:-517px; along with targeting direct id's it is also not working. So is there any problem with my code?

```css
.img-container{
width:1550px;
  border:4px solid black;
  padding:6px;
}

.crousel{
  width:516px;
  border:6px solid magenta;
  height:350px;
  display:flex;
  
}
img{
  padding:6px;
}

.toggle-button:checked ~ .box {
  translate(X):transform(-517px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="img-container">
    <div class="crousel">
    <label for="toggle1"></label>
      <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/10/06/11/50/dog-5632005__340.jpg" alt="" class="box">
    <label for="toggle2"></label>
      <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/09/12/09/26/gorilla-5565295__340.jpg" alt="" class="box">
    <label for="toggle3"></label>
      <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/09/14/17/19/beach-5571545__340.jpg" alt="" class="box">
      </div>
    </div>
  <div class="buttons">
    <input type="radio" name="button" id="toggle1" class="toggle-button">
     <input type="radio" name="button" id="toggle2" class="toggle-button">
     <input type="radio" name="button" id="toggle3" class="toggle-button">
     
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The transform syntax is wrong and you need to use the checkbox HTML above the images because CSS does not select bottom to top. Move it outside the parent container and select the parent element `img-container` directly with that selector like this - `.toggle-button:checked ~ .img-container .crousel .box`

Comment: @m4n0 could you show me a little bit of code how to do this?

Comment: You can take help of this: https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-build-a-simple-slideshow-with-the-css-checkbox-hack--cms-34465

Comment: @m4n0 if you don't mind can you clarify your answer little bit specially with checkbox HTML ?

Comment: `.toggle-button:checked ~ .box` will not select anything because there is nothing to select afterwards for the CSS. CSS does not render from bottom to top.

Comment: This code is very far from that you want but it illustrates a principle: I just swapped labels and radio buttons

https://codesandbox.io/s/solitary-glitter-gnoi4?file=/index.html

Comment: @m4n0 Don't mind I want to learn that's why i am asking can you show me the correct code with same classes and id's.

Comment: Here it is: https://codepen.io/tutsplus/pen/MWYXJdj

Comment: @Alexandr Thanks a lot for the code but could you clear my concepts about this slider ?what's wrong with the code what mistakes I have made?

Comment: @m4n0 thanks for this If I found any thing confusing  I will ask?

Comment: @ShayanKanwal Sure!

Comment: @m4n0 could you please  give me the correct code for the above slider with the same classes and id's

Comment: You can use this service: https://www.upwork.com/ or https://www.codementor.io/

Comment: @m4n0 i want to learn not to hire any one for that correct my code if possible or tell me some of my mistakes brother

Comment: @Ishita Ray I have tried your code but it not worked as much for me i think there are some mistakes. could you put them up please?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64431710/can-anyone-help-me-with-that-when-i-am-clicking-radio-buttons-why-images-are-not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this like that way...

```css
.slider {
  width: 500px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.rollSlider {
display: flex;
width: 1500px;
}
img {
  max-width: 500px;
}
input#slide1:checked ~ .slider .rollSlider {
  transform: translate(0px);
  transition: all 300ms ease;
}
input#slide2:checked ~ .slider .rollSlider {
  transform: translate(-500px);
  transition: all 300ms ease;
}
input#slide3:checked ~ .slider .rollSlider {
  transform: translate(-1000px);
  transition: all 300ms ease;
}
```

```html
<input id="slide1" type="radio" name="slide" checked>
<input id="slide2" name="slide" type="radio">
<input id="slide3" name="slide" type="radio">
<div class="slider">
<div class="rollSlider">
<label for="slide1">
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/4040806/pexels-photo-4040806.jpeg">
</label> 
  <label for="slide2">
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/4686833/pexels-photo-4686833.jpeg">
</label> 
  <label for="slide3">
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/4722021/pexels-photo-4722021.jpeg">
</label> 
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried your code but it not worked as much for me i think there are some mistakes. could you put them u please ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64431710/can-anyone-help-me-with-that-when-i-am-clicking-radio-buttons-why-images-are-not