# Why these radio buttons are not showing? how can make them visible?

Tags: html, css

I have tried z-index on input but its not working how can I fix that  and please check this my other other question put my mistakes up
[Why when radio button is checked the images are not sliding out of out of container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64412383/why-when-radio-button-is-checked-the-images-are-not-sliding-out-of-out-of-contai?noredirect=1#comment113900821_64412383)

please resolve my confusion

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.img-container {
  width: 1550px;
  border: 4px solid black;
  padding: 6px;
}

.crousel {
  width: 516px;
  border: 6px solid magenta;
  height: 350px;
  display: flex;
}
img {
  padding: 6px;
}

.toggle-button {
  display: none;
}

.box {
  transition-duration: 1s;
  transition-property: transform;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

.toggle-button:nth-child(1):checked ~ .box:nth-child(1) {
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.toggle-button:nth-child(2):checked ~ .box:nth-child(2) {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.toggle-button:nth-child(2):checked ~ .box:nth-child(2){
  transform: translateX(-200%);
}
input {

  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./src/styles.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="img-container">
      <div class="crousel">
        <input type="radio" name="button" id="toggle1" class="toggle-button" />
        <input type="radio" name="button" id="toggle2" class="toggle-button" />
        <input type="radio" name="button" id="toggle3" class="toggle-button" />

        <img
          src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/10/06/11/50/dog-5632005__340.jpg"
          alt=""
          class="box"
        />
        <img
          src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/09/12/09/26/gorilla-5565295__340.jpg"
          alt=""
          class="box"
        />
        <img
          src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/09/14/17/19/beach-5571545__340.jpg"
          alt=""
          class="box"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
      <label for="toggle1">1</label>
      <label for="toggle2">2</label>
      <label for="toggle3">3</label>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: if you mean radio button, simple use console dev and see which property have that radio ...  Tips: `display:none;`

Comment: @SimoneRossaini what is console dev and could you check my other question

Comment: in google chrome ctrl+maiusc+i, search your radio button and see the  property

Comment: @SimoneRossaini thanks for your answer could you please tell me how to make img slider with editing this code a lot . This means a lot me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

uhh I dont know what you are trying to make but i made it work. For some reason `nth-child(1)` was not working for `box` so i gave it `box-1` `box-2` `box-3` classes and now it is working. lmk if it helped you

```css
.toggle-button:nth-child(1):checked ~ .box-1 {
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.toggle-button:nth-child(2):checked ~ .box-2 {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.toggle-button:nth-child(2):checked ~ .box-3{
  transform: translateX(-200%);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/10/06/11/50/dog-5632005__340.jpg" alt="" class="box box-1"/>
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/09/12/09/26/gorilla-5565295__340.jpg" alt="" class="box box-2"/>
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/09/14/17/19/beach-5571545__340.jpg" alt="" class="box box-3"/>
```

Comment: Brother thanks a lot for this your code works for me thanks a lot again! and could you tell me how to make slider with pure css with controls.

Comment: tell me which type of slider u want? i will give u the link 
https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/
if you dont under what's going on just let me know. i will help you,
 and btw i have never seen a slider in which js is not used

Answer (score 0):

You have set display property of your `toggle-button` to none. Simply replace the `none` with `block`

```css
.toggle-button {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: this code works and thanks a lot for this but when I am checking radio buttons the images are not sliding in short slider not works

Comment: Are you making a slider?

Comment: yes I am trying to make slider with pure css with controls could you tell me how to make with controls.

Comment: i use external code for css. you can fully customize it easily