# When I am clicking radio buttons why images are not moving?

Tags: html, css

Why my slider is not working? I have tried all but nothing works, I am looking to find where the mistakes are in the code. How can I make it to work?

```css
.img-container{
  border:2px solid black;
  padding:6px;
  width:1660px;
}

.crousel >img  {
margin:4px;
}
.crousel{
  border:4px solid magenta;
  width:517px;
  overflow:;
  display:flex;
}

#slide1:checked ~ .img-container .crousel .box{
  
 transform: translate(0px);
  transition: all 300ms ease;
}
#slide2:checked ~ .img-container .crousel .box{
  
 transform: translate(-500px);
  transition: all 300ms ease;
}
#slide3:checked ~ .img-container .crousel .box{
  
 transform: translate(-1000px);
  transition: all 300ms ease;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="whole-slider">
    <input type="radio" id="slide1" name="img" checked>
     <input type="radio" id="slide2" name="img">
     <input type="radio" id="slide3" name="img">
    
    <div class="img-container">
      <div class="crousel">
        <label for="slide1"></label>
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/10/06/11/50/dog-5632005__340.jpg" alt="" class=".box">
        
        <label for="slide2"></label>
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/09/12/09/26/gorilla-5565295__340.jpg" alt="" class=".box">
        
        <label for="slide3"></label>
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/09/14/17/19/beach-5571545__340.jpg" alt="" class=".box">
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your html, in your img, you wrote `class=".box"` instead of `class="box"`.

And put `img` tag between label tag because it is pointing to `for`.

It will work fine with this modification.

```css
.img-container{
  border:2px solid black;
  padding:6px;
  width:1660px;
}

.crousel >img  {
margin:4px;
}
.crousel{
  border:4px solid magenta;
  width:517px;
  overflow:;
  display:flex;
}

#slide1:checked ~ .img-container .crousel .box{
  
 transform: translate(0px);
  transition: all 300ms ease;
}
#slide2:checked ~ .img-container .crousel .box{
  
 transform: translate(-500px);
  transition: all 300ms ease;
}
#slide3:checked ~ .img-container .crousel .box{
  
 transform: translate(-1000px);
  transition: all 300ms ease;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="whole-slider">
    <input type="radio" id="slide1" name="img" checked>
     <input type="radio" id="slide2" name="img">
     <input type="radio" id="slide3" name="img">
    
    <div class="img-container">
      <div class="crousel">
        <label for="slide1">
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/10/06/11/50/dog-5632005__340.jpg" alt="" class="box">
        </label>
        <label for="slide2">
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/09/12/09/26/gorilla-5565295__340.jpg" alt="" class="box">
        </label>
        <label for="slide3"> <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/09/14/17/19/beach-5571545__340.jpg" alt="" class="box">
        </label>
        <img
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot brother for this answer it works and thanks for putting my mistakes up again thanks a lot ! –

Comment: @MaxiGui - in general, if you find a typographical error solves a problem, it is not worth answering. Just comment and, if you have enough rep, vote to close.

Comment: @halfer ok I will make this way then

Comment: @halfer Please have a look to very similar just posted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64497438/why-the-images-are-not-sliding-when-the-checkbox-is-checked/ Probably some student based on the snippet... But I cannot set this subject as duplicate as it is closed (obviously neither you or I could know...)

Answer (score 0):

1. I have put img tag between label tag...
2. class=".box" it's not right. It would be class="box"...

```css
.img-container{
  border:2px solid black;
  padding:6px;
  width:1660px;
}

.crousel >img  {
margin:4px;
}
.crousel{
  border:4px solid magenta;
  width:517px;
  overflow:;
  display:flex;
}

#slide1:checked ~ .img-container .crousel .box{
  
 transform: translate(0px);
  transition: all 300ms ease;
}
#slide2:checked ~ .img-container .crousel .box{
  
 transform: translate(-500px);
  transition: all 300ms ease;
}
#slide3:checked ~ .img-container .crousel .box{
  
 transform: translate(-1000px);
  transition: all 300ms ease;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="whole-slider">
    <input type="radio" id="slide1" name="img" checked>
     <input type="radio" id="slide2" name="img">
     <input type="radio" id="slide3" name="img">
    
    <div class="img-container">
      <div class="crousel">
        <label for="slide1">
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/10/06/11/50/dog-5632005__340.jpg" alt="" class="box">
        </label>
        <label for="slide2">
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/09/12/09/26/gorilla-5565295__340.jpg" alt="" class="box">
        </label>
        <label for="slide3"> <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/09/14/17/19/beach-5571545__340.jpg" alt="" class="box">
        </label>
        <img
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks a lot for this answer it works. I have an question that when we put direct at the place of .box  > img why its not working

Comment: Probably because you it is pointing to your label, not to your image as it is searching to the « for » in `label`