# why the images are not sliding when the checkbox is checked?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make image slider (with controls) with pure css So, when I am checking checkbox the images are not sliding so what's the problem with the code and can anybody tell how to make slider (with controls like one button on left and one button on right for sliding) only using pure css.

```css
.accordion{
  display:flex;
  width:100%;
  border:3px solid yellow;
  padding:6px;
}
.img-wrapper{
 display:flex; 
  width:510px;
  border:3px solid black;
  //overflow:hidden;
}
.img-container{
  width:500px;
  border:2px solid magenta;
  
}

#toggle1:checked ~  .img-container .box{
  transform: translate(0px);
  transition: all 300ms ease;
}
#toggle2:checked ~  .img-container .box{
  transform: translate(-500px);
  transition: all 300ms ease;
}
#toggle3:checked ~ .img-container .box {
  transform: translate(-1000px);
  transition: all 300ms ease ;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="accordion">
    <div class="img-wrapper">
    <div class="accordion-tab">
      <input type="checkbox" id="toggle1" class="toggle-button">
      <label for="toggle1"></label>
      <div class="img-container">
      <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/12/16/17/13/berlin-4699765__340.jpg" alt="" class=.box>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="accordion-tab">
      <input type="checkbox" id="toggle1" class="toggle-button">
      <label for="toggle1"></label>
      <div class="img-container">
      <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/10/05/10/51/cat-5628953__340.jpg" alt="" class=.box>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="accordion-tab">
      <input type="checkbox" id="toggle1" class="toggle-button">
      <label for="toggle1"></label>
      <div class="img-container">
      <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/10/19/09/44/woman-5667299__340.jpg" alt="" class=.box>
        </div>
    </div>
      </div>
    
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: All your input are having same `id` and same `for` label. ID should be unique, as yours as human. try to remember that

Comment: @MaxiGui brother thanks for answer but i am trying to make the image slider with controls how can I do that with pure css

Comment: My answer below is pure CSS & HTML. It is using `radio` input

Comment: @MaxiGui brother I have seen your code below  I am asking you for the slider with previous and next button using pure css

Comment: Maybe you could try to make or open another question for that. As it is quite another work ? (I know that what you are doing is an exercice.)

Comment: @MaxiGui brother here is the example of slider here you can see the right and left angles with pre and next respectively and other than this is there any property in css on which we can check many times.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223515/discussion-between-shayan-kanwal-and-maxigui).

Answer (score 1):

So: All your input are having same `id` and same `for` label. ID should be unique, as yours as human. try to remember that.

You should not use type `checkbox` but `radio`.

In your html, in your img, you wrote `class=".box"` instead of `class="box"`.

And put `img` tag between label tag because it is pointing to `for`.

It will work fine with this modification.

```css
.img-container{
  border:2px solid black;
  padding:6px;
  width:1660px;
}

.crousel >img  {
margin:4px;
}
.crousel{
  border:4px solid magenta;
  width:517px;
  overflow:;
  display:flex;
}

#slide1:checked ~ .img-container .crousel .box{
  
 transform: translate(0px);
  transition: all 300ms ease;
}
#slide2:checked ~ .img-container .crousel .box{
  
 transform: translate(-500px);
  transition: all 300ms ease;
}
#slide3:checked ~ .img-container .crousel .box{
  
 transform: translate(-1000px);
  transition: all 300ms ease;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="whole-slider">
    <input type="radio" id="slide1" name="img" checked>
     <input type="radio" id="slide2" name="img">
     <input type="radio" id="slide3" name="img">
    
    <div class="img-container">
      <div class="crousel">
        <label for="slide1">
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/12/16/17/13/berlin-4699765__340.jpg" alt="" class="box">
        </label>
        
        <label for="slide2">
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/10/05/10/51/cat-5628953__340.jpg" alt="" class="box">
        </label>
        <label for="slide3"> <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/10/19/09/44/woman-5667299__340.jpg" alt="" class="box">
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

### DEMO ONLY CSS made by [Mayur Birle](https://codepen.io/mayurbirle/pen/ppqRoZ?editors=1100)

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Just+Another+Hand');
body, html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Just Another Hand', cursive;
  overflow-X: hidden;
}
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
  width: 70%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 40%;
  user-select: none;
  background-color: #1c1c1c;
  box-shadow: 0 11px 22px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 7px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}
.container input {
  display: none;
}
.container .slide_img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
.container .slide_img img {
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
}
.container .slide_img .prev, .container .slide_img .next {
  width: 12%;
  height: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255, 82, 82, 0.2);
  z-index: 99;
  transition: 0.45s;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}
.container .slide_img .next {
  right: 0;
}
.container .slide_img .prev {
  left: 0;
}
.container .slide_img .prev:hover, .container .slide_img .next:hover {
  transition: 0.3s;
  background-color: rgba(255, 82, 82, 0.8);
}
.container .slide_img .prev span, .container .slide_img .next span {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border: solid 20px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.container .slide_img .prev span {
  border-color: transparent #fff transparent transparent;
  right: 35%;
}
.container .slide_img .next span {
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #fff;
  left: 35%;
}
.container #nav_slide {
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 12%;
  height: 11px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 99;
  cursor: default;
}
.container #nav_slide .dots {
  top: -5px;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  margin: 0 3px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  transition: 0.4s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.container #nav_slide #dot1:hover {
  background: #795548;
}
.container #nav_slide #dot2:hover {
  background: #F44336;
}
.container #nav_slide #dot3:hover {
  background: #2196F3;
}
.container #nav_slide #dot4:hover {
  background: #4CAF50;
}
#i1:checked ~ #one, #i2:checked ~ #two, #i3:checked ~ #three, #i4:checked ~ #four {
  z-index: 9;
  animation: scroll 1s ease-in-out;
}
#i1:checked ~ #nav_slide #dot1 {
  background: #795548;
}
#i2:checked ~ #nav_slide #dot2 {
  background: #F44336;
}
#i3:checked ~ #nav_slide #dot3 {
  background: #2196F3;
}
#i4:checked ~ #nav_slide #dot4 {
  background: #4CAF50;
}
@keyframes scroll {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 685px) {
  .container {
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 55%;
  }
  .container .slide_img .prev, .container .slide_img .next {
    width: 15%;
  }
  .container .slide_img .prev span, .container .slide_img .next span {
    border: solid 12px;
  }
  .container .slide_img .prev span {
    border-color: transparent #fff transparent transparent;
  }
  .container .slide_img .next span {
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #fff;
  }
  .container #nav_slide .dots {
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
  }
}
.yt {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #2196F3;
  box-shadow: 0 11px 22px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 7px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  transition: 0.4s;
  opacity: 0.4;
}
.yt a {
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 23px;
  top: 4px;
}
.yt:hover {
  transition: 0.3s;
  box-shadow: none;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    

    <input type="radio" id="i1" name="images" checked/>
    <input type="radio" id="i2" name="images" />
    <input type="radio" id="i3" name="images" />
    <input type="radio" id="i4" name="images"  />
    
    <div class="slide_img" id="one">            
            
            <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/12/16/17/13/berlin-4699765__340.jpg">
            
                <label class="prev" for="i4"><span></span></label>
                <label class="next" for="i2"><span></span></label>  
        
    </div>
    
    <div class="slide_img" id="two">
        
            <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/e5OShF/cropped_800_480_111290.jpg " >
            
                <label class="prev" for="i1"><span></span></label>
                <label class="next" for="i3"><span></span></label>
        
    </div>
            
    <div class="slide_img" id="three">
            <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/10/05/10/51/cat-5628953__340.jpg"> 
            
                <label class="prev" for="i2"><span></span></label>
                <label class="next" for="i4"><span></span></label>
    </div>


    <div class="slide_img" id="four">
            <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/10/19/09/44/woman-5667299__340.jpg">   
            
                <label class="prev" for="i3"><span></span></label>
                <label class="next" for="i1"><span></span></label>

    </div>

    <div id="nav_slide">
        <label for="i1" class="dots" id="dot1"></label>
        <label for="i2" class="dots" id="dot2"></label>
        <label for="i3" class="dots" id="dot3"></label>
        <label for="i4" class="dots" id="dot4"></label>
    </div>
        
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't add classes like that => `class=.box`

It should be `class="box"`

Replace this and try again